# How to Migrate from AzDevops server to existing organization in AzDevops service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-server-2019

How to migrate Boards, Pipeline, Test Plan, Artifacts and Repo from on-prem azdevops server to Existing organization in azdevops service? Is it any different tool available?

Answer (score 1):

There is no officially supported way to merge 2 Azure DevOps Organisations or an Azure DevOps Server with an Azure DevOps organization.

With the official import tooling each Project Collection on your Azure DevOps Server will be mapped to a **new** Azure DevOps Organization.

There are all kinds of tools that can replay the history of work items and test plans. You can git mirror repositories from one place to another. You can use git-tfs or 3rd party tools to migrate TFVC history from one organization to another. Azure Pipelines can be exported/imported and Azure Artefacts can be downloaded/uploaded with the native tools for each kind of supported artifact feed.

This process is complicated, cannot be 100% and will cause certain data to be altered or lost. Since work item IDs and changesets and test case/plan IDs are unique per Organization it's impossible to migrate with these ids in tact. Hence all kinds of mapping and remapping is required. Certain dates (like Created Date, Changed Date) can't be overridden and will be reset to the time of migration.

Some tools to look at:

- [Azure DevOps Sync Migrator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration): Work Items
- [Git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs): TFVC -> Git:
- [OpsHub Azure DevOps migrator](https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-azure-devops-migrator/)
- `git clone --mirror` & `git push --mirror` for git repo migrations

But in the end, the simplest way is to just create a new organization.

Comment: It's a bummer that there's no official way to migrate into an existing organization. Are there any 3rd party tools that do that, if yes, can you mention some of those?

Comment: I already mentioned a number in the answer. I added links to the most common tools. But there's nothing that's easy in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

The different migration options are explained in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migrate-from-tfs?view=azure-devops). There are some existing tool (see this ***High fidelity database migration*** option) but do not expect a 1:1 migration, you might loose some stuff in between. Depending on the criticality of your data, it might not be an issue though and could be enough.

The best probably remains to do it manually/using the APIs.

Comment: Thanks Jul_DW , 
Is this help to migrate existing organization, somewhere i believe the tool will create Organization and project itself and throws error if its already created. Sorry this confusing me lot.